# LINQ to Entities Transaction Performance Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

```
public void Register(decimal groupId, decimal deptId, decimal employeeId)
{
    using (EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities())
    {
       using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot }))
       {
          var course = db.Courses.Where(s => s.GroupId == groupId && s.DepartmentId == deptId).ToList();                  

          foreach (var item in course)
          {
             var filledSeats = db.CourseRegistrations.Count(c => c.CourseId == item.CourseId && c.DepartmentId == deptId && (c.CancelledFl == null || c.CancelledFl == false));

             if (item.AllotedSeats <= filledSeats)
             {
                throw new Exception("Sorry! Seats are not available for " + db.Groups.Where(s => s.GroupId == item.GroupId).Select(s => s.GroupName).FirstOrDefault());
             }
             if (!db.CourseRegistrations.Any(s => s.EmployeeId == employeeId && s.CourseId == item.CourseId && (s.CancelledFl == false || s.CancelledFl == null)))
             {
                 var courseRegister = new CourseRegistration();
                 db.CourseRegistrations.Add(courseRegister);
                 courseRegister.CourseId = item.CourseId;
                 courseRegister.EmployeeId = employeeId;
                 courseRegister.CreatedBy = 1;
                 courseRegister.CreatedDt = DateTime.Now;
                 courseRegister.RecordVa = 1;

                 item.FilledSeats = item.FilledSeats + 1;
             }
          }
          db.SaveChanges();
          scope.Complete();
       }    
    }  
}
```

Consider the above code. It is a function which is eventually called when a request is sent to an `ASP.NET WebAPI` controller.

The function simply registers an employee to a course after checking seat availability. Some 200 employees would register for courses at the same time.

I am using `Snapshot Isolation` for every transaction.

My problem is in **performance**. It is **slow**. Sometimes it times out.

My question is **why**? What part of my code have I gone wrong? What really happens in all these transactions? What waits or what locks?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple calls to the database inside your for loop, which means you eat the total cost of db request latency 2 x course.length times, when you should only need to eat it once, maybe twice.  See if you can bring the necessary data from `db.CourseRegistrations` outside the loop, possibly as part of the same query joined with the data from Courses.  Then you can do the operations inside the loop in memory, which will be orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing many updates/inserts the EF automatically tracks these changes by default, this can really hurt performance if you are updating many records. To help this you can turn off the [AutoDetectChangesEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj556205.aspx) feature just before you do your bulk update and then back on again as soon as you are finished;

```
        try
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            //loop through your updates here
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
```